# ocassional "Permission denied @ rb_sysopen" by a ruby script

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, xfs

i'm working on a ubuntu 16.04 box with :

> ruby 2.3.1p112
>
> filesystem : XFS

i have written a ruby script which writes small & unique text files to a group of folders, each writes would occur in around 5 seconds, and in each time the folder to be written is random.

but then at times this error would occur :

```
"Permission denied @ rb_sysopen"
```

the strange thing is it may happen to the same folder which can be written normally without error just a minute or so ago. so this is not related to file permissions.

i have also unmount the related disk for a disk check via "xfs_repair", nothing unusual found, and after i remount it the same error would come out in an irregular manner.

any hints please?

Answer (score 1):

Can't speculate on the root cause, but if you are *absolutely* sure this is a transient issue and you *just need to make it work* you can try Ruby's `retry`.

```
def write_file(file, content)
  File.write(file, content)
rescue Errno::EACCES
  retry
end
```

I would also add a limit of retries just in case this is not transient.

```
def write_file(file, content)
  retries ||= 3
  return if (retries -= 1) == 0

  File.write(file, content)
rescue Errno::EACCES
  retry
end
```

You may also need to throw a `sleep` in there in case this is time sensitive. You need to experiment. Just be careful not to turn this piece into a blocking code.

Obviously, this brute force is far from the ideal, but sometimes you got to do what you got to do.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  indeed i've also tried "sleep 2", and didn't help. but would definitely test on your "retry" advice.